# Removing columns from a dataframe with a common string but keeping the first

Tags: r

In my dataframe frame I have columns with names like this:

```
stockA_1,stockA_2,stockA_3,stockA_4
```

I would like to delete all rows from my df which have the common string `"stockA_"` but I would like to keep only the first column with this synthetic `"stockA_1"`

How is it possible to make it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly: Do you want to keep only the first column matching `stockA_` ? If so, maybe something like `subset(df, select = grep("stockA_", colnames(df), value = TRUE)[1])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with base functions:

```
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:35, 5, 7))
names(d) <- c("AA", "stockA_1", "BBB", "stockA_2", "stockA_3", "CCCCC", "stockA_4")
d[,-which(grepl("^stockA_", names(d)))[-1]]
```

The result is:

```
> d[,-which(grepl("^stockA_", names(d)))[-1]]
  AA stockA_1 BBB CCCCC
1  1        6  11    26
2  2        7  12    27
3  3        8  13    28
4  4        9  14    29
5  5       10  15    30
```

---

If you want to conserve the column "stockA_1" (which is eventually not in the first place under the "stockA_"-columns) then you can do

```
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:35, 5, 7))
names(d) <- c("AA", "stockA_11", "BBB", "stockA_2", "stockA_1", "CCCCC", "stockA_4")
i <- (!grepl("^stockA_", names(d))) | grepl("^stockA_1$", names(d))
d[,i]
```

with the result:

```
> d[,i]
  AA BBB stockA_1 CCCCC
1  1  11       21    26
2  2  12       22    27
3  3  13       23    28
4  4  14       24    29
5  5  15       25    30
```

Comment: If you want, make it more generic so that it covers cases where stockA_1 is not the first column with the "stockA_" pattern. Something like : `d[,-which(grepl("^stockA_[^stockA_1]", names(d)))]`

Comment: Yes I was checking that now. I am now trying to learn regular expressions I am not really good at it unfortunately :(

Comment: Try this: `d[,-which(grepl("^stockA_[2-9]|^stockA_1.", names(d)))]`

Answer (score 0):

Using the data table (if I have understood the problem correctly that is):

```
require(data.table)
data <- data.table(stockA_1 = c(1, 2, 3), stockA_2 = c(3, 4, 7), stockA_3 = c(4, 5, 6))

columns <- setdiff(grep("stockA_", names(data)), grep("stockA_1", names(data)))
data[, (columns):= NULL]
```

Comment: ? `d <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:35, 5, 7));
names(d) <- c("AA", "stockA_11", "BBB", "stockA_2", "stockA_1", "CCCCC", "stockA_4");
data <- as.data.table(d)`